# net core OData, different model per request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

OData has always the same EDM model created at startup

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        //odataBuilder.EntitySet<Tag>("Tags");
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<Tag>("OperateTable");
        //odataBuilder.EntitySet<Tag>("Books");

        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

I changed the OData source code a few months ago, to have a middleware that allows me to change the EDM model per user. This already exists or I should make a pull request with this?

Thank you,

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the repo maintainers about a PR?

Comment: Doing that now. I was hoping for a direct answer like "yes its already available"

Comment: find the repository at https://github.com/OData. any PR is welcome

Comment: It shall be done!